# Generating sequence of averages of averages of partial sums

Tags: syntax

I have been given the following code that generates the sequence of averages (of the partial sums) of Grandi's series:

```
ClearAll

PartialSum[0]= 0;

For[i = 0, i<5000, i++, PartialSum[i + 1]= PartialSum[i]+ (i + 1)^0 (-1)^i]

SumOfPartialSum[0]= 0;

For[i = 0, i<5000, i++,

SumOfPartialSum[i + 1]= SumOfPartialSum[i]+ PartialSum[i + 1];

Average[i + 1]= SumOfPartialSum[i + 1]/(i + 1);

Print[N[Average[i + 1]]]]
```

I want to modify it in order to generate the terms of the sequence of averages of averages of averages of the partial sums of the following series: 1 - 2^2 + 3^2 - 4^2 + 5^2 - ... and so on. I have figured out how to modify it such that it will generate the sequence of averages of the above series, but thus far I have been unsuccessful at generating any further averages.

Any help is much appreciated as I am relatively new to Mathematica.

Comment: What is the purpose of (i+1)^0 ?

Comment: Something like `With[{terms = 50, k = 2}, Nest[Accumulate[#]/Range[Length[#]] &, Accumulate[N[PadRight[{}, terms, {1, -1}] Range[terms]^2, 20]], k]]` then?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ps = Accumulate[(1 + #)^2 (-1)^# & /@ Range[0, 9]]
(* or ps = Accumulate[Range[#]^2 (-1)^Range[0, # - 1]] *)
```

> {1, -3, 6, -10, 15, -21, 28, -36, 45, -55}

```
sps = Accumulate[ps]
```

> {1, -2, 4, -6, 9, -12, 16, -20, 25, -30}

```
means = MapIndexed[#/First[#2] &, sps]
```

> {1, -1, 4/3, -(3/2), 9/5, -2, 16/7, -(5/2), 25/9, -3}

Combine in single function:

```
ClearAll[meanspsF]
meanspsF = With[{sps = Accumulate[Accumulate[Range[#]^2 (-1)^Range[0, # - 1]]]}, 
    MapIndexed[#/First[#2] &, sps]] &;

meanspsF[9]
```

> {1, -1, 4/3, -(3/2), 9/5, -2, 16/7, -(5/2), 25/9, -3}

```
meanspsF[5]
```

> {1, -1, 4/3, -(3/2), 9/5, -2}

Comment: So for the "mean of means"  I would then type MapIndexed[#/First[#2] &, means], right?

Comment: @Jack, i think just `Mean[means]`, no?